# LocationManager problem after updating the application in iphone

Tags: iphone, gps, location

I am using LocationManger class to get user's current location. When i install application from App store and run application first time application ask me that " APP would like to use your current location." followed by "Don't Allow" and "Ok" button. At this point of time application works fine.

Now I uninstall application and reinstall the same application from App store. Now when i tried to run application, it doesn't prompt me same location dialog and also Location Manager failed to retrieve the location with kCLErrorDenied error.

I also tried with two other application on App store, same problem happened.

Anyone has idea about this behaviour?? How to retrieve user's current location in this situation?

Thanks,
Jim.

Answer (score 0):

If the user has denied you access to your location, they have to go into the settings menu -> General -> Location services and choose your app from the list there.

Until they do that, your app won't have access to the GPS. Sorry!

Comment: When i checked from Setting->General->Location Services, for my application location service is on even though i am getting same error.I also found some blogs where people are complaining the same thing. Mostly this is issue with iOS 4.1 as per my knowledge.

Comment: Oh. In that case I'm afraid I have no idea :(.  I'd make a test app that displays the same error and send it to apple as a bug?

Comment: Thanks..Hope it will be resolved in upcoming OS. For more information this is not reproducible on iOS 3.0.

Comment: If you want to try the same behavior then download any GPS related application(MotionX,GPSTracker). Run the application. Now delete the application and again reinstall the same application. Now run the application and it will failed to get your current location. Can you please check it and let me know the results ??